# Is there a way to transfer files from a large amount of damaged CDs?

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer, compact-disc

I'm trying to pull a lot of files off of a lot of old CDs, and I'm getting all kinds of errors and hangs. The CDs are old and covered with scratches, so it's to be expected, but I have still been able to recover some of the files.

I was wondering if there is a way to skip the problem files but generate a list of skipped files so I can see what got missed.

I'm using Windows 7, but I am also comfortable in Linux if there are more options in that environment. I am also using a Samsung external CD reader with a USB interface.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/417391/how-to-copy-files-with-an-option-for-skipping-stuck-files

Comment: Why not fix the discs first with something like SkipDoctor?

Comment: I think the question you linked is similar enough that it answers my question. The main thing I was looking for that I couldn't find anywhere else was `robocopy /V` which outputs a log file showing all the files skipped during a copy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use xcopy through a Command Prompt o:

xcopy $SOURCE $DESTINATION /C /E /Q

The /C flag forces xcopy to ignore any issues with copying; the /E flag orders xcopy to copy folders (even empty ones), and the /Q flag makes it a quiet operation (otherwise, you'll get an entry for each thing copied).

An example would be

```
xcopy d:\*.* c:\recovery /C /E /Q
```